# Suggestions for carrying out automation using docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am quite good at docker. I need your views regarding what approach should I follow for the following:

I need to build a **distribution tarball** of a package `X`. The obvious steps are :

```
$ git clone X && cd X # get source
$ ./autogen.sh # install some extra packages for building project
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ make test
$ make dist # create tarball
```

As part of the application requirement, I need to get the `output` and `success flag` of each above command. I have the following two approaches:

- Make a `dockerfile` using a base image of a distro and include all the above steps in it. And, finally export the tarball. The process will fail if any intermediate step is failed. But using this approach I am facing issues in parsing the output of individual commands (`make test`, `./configure`) ? Moreover I have to use `--no-cache` each time building as I am doing `git clone` and my repo is very frequently updated
- Other is I run the above steps individually on a running container. Using this I can easily parse the output of a step and then proceed to next step if the previous succeeds.

So, which approach should I follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it's getting into an opinion question. That said, if it was me, I'd do it as a Dockerfile.

- Build everything common first, anything you can to setup the environment, so these steps can be cached.
- Insert a cache breaking parameter on the git clone step. (pass an ARG of the timestamp to the `docker build`, and then `RUN STAMP=${TIMESTAMP} git clone`. If the clone takes too long, you could do two clones, one that gets cached and rarely updated (daily or monthly based on your preferences), and then a pull that you run every time.
- Include your output parser inside the container, run that in your `RUN` commands, and on any errors in the parsing, exit with a non-zero code to abend the build. Send all the output to a local log with the `tee` command.
- On a successful build, you can do a `docker cp` to copy the logs out of the container if you need them there.

My logic to avoid a running container is that it's less likely to have a clean starting state, very easy to get corrupted by a second concurrent run of the same test on the container, and if you don't reset it each time, you could have a false positive not knowing that prior runs left an initial state that you can't easily reproduce elsewhere. The Dockerfile is also much more portable.

Comment: The answer is quite visionary ! How can I run my output parser inside the container, can you give some brief example/explanation ?

Comment: Really depends on what you were already using for your parser. `RUN make | tee /logs/make.log | parser` if you want to parse the output directly, or just do a `RUN make | tee /logs/make.log && parser /logs/make.log` if you want them separate.